# Anthos - GKE - Unable to deploy apps using kf

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-anthos, google-anthos-service-mesh

I have deployed "Anthos Sample Deployment" from marketplace on GCP. I see it created GKE cluster and it's registerd in Anothos as well. I see pods for sample app is also deployed. After cluster was up and running I wanted to try "kf" (https://cloud.google.com/migrate/kf/docs/2.7/getting-started), so to congifure "kf" I executed below mentioned steps from google documentation (https://cloud.google.com/migrate/kf/docs/2.7/install#install)

When I try to run "`kf create-space test-space-3`", it prints "Space requested, waiting for subcomponents to be created", but the command never completes. So next I tried to execute same command with "--log-http" flag, and I see it makes few API calls..

- 1st API: GET /api/v1/namespaces/kf - 200 OKResponse
- 2nd API: GET /api/v1/namespaces/kf - 200 OKResponse
- 3rd API: POST /apis/kf.dev/v1alpha1/spaces - 201 Created
- 4th API: GET /apis/kf.dev/v1alpha1/spaces/test-space-3 - 200 OK
- 5th API: <Same as 4th>

It keeps calling 4th API, and never completes. I am not sure if I am missing something.
4th API Response:

```
{"apiVersion":"kf.dev/v1alpha1","kind":"Space","metadata":{"creationTimestamp":"2022-03-02T13:45:25Z","generation":1,"managedFields":[{"apiVersion":"kf.dev/v1alpha1","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:spec":{".":{},"f:buildConfig":{".":{},"f:defaultToV3Stack":{}},"f:networkConfig":{".":{},"f:appNetworkPolicy":{},"f:buildNetworkPolicy":{}},"f:runtimeConfig":{}}},"manager":"kf","operation":"Update","time":"2022-03-02T13:45:25Z"}],"name":"test-space-3","resourceVersion":"825403","uid":"3cf7ef08-1ab1-4473-b7da-dd6511a6a775"},"spec":{"buildConfig":{"containerRegistry":"us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/<project-id>/demo-dev-kf-cluster","defaultToV3Stack":null,"serviceAccount":"kf-builder"},"networkConfig":{"appNetworkPolicy":{"egress":"PermitAll","ingress":"PermitAll"},"buildNetworkPolicy":{"egress":"PermitAll","ingress":"PermitAll"}},"runtimeConfig":{}}}
```

Same behavior when I try to deploy any app..
Command: `kf push nginx --docker-image=nginx:latest --log-http`

- 1st API: GET /api/v1/namespaces/kf - 200 OKResponse
- 2nd API: GET /apis/kf.dev/v1alpha1/spaces/test-space-1 - 200 OK
- 3rd API: GET /api/v1/namespaces/kf - 200 OK
- 4th API: GET /apis/kf.dev/v1alpha1/namespaces/test-space-1/apps/nginx ~ 404 Not Found, since this is the first time I am deploying this app
- 5th API: POST /apis/kf.dev/v1alpha1/namespaces/test-space-1/apps ~ 201 Created
- 6th API: GET /apis/kf.dev/v1alpha1/namespaces/test-space-1/apps/nginx ~ 200 OK

and it keeps calling 6th API continuously, and command never completes. In 2nd API response I see below error. Not sure if this is something which is causing the issue.

```
{
"lastTransitionTime": "2022-03-01T13:56:05Z",
"message": "Error occurred while creating IAMPolicy: the server could not find the requested resource",
"reason": "ReconciliationError",
"status": "False",
"type": "IAMPolicyReady"
}
```

Any pointer to resolve this will be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Did you met the kf requirements? I would recommend you to raise a support ticket with GCP support as there are a lot of variables to inspect like the GKE version or your daemonsets... did you already inspected the output of kf doctor --retries=20 ?